Create unique elements (ft.containers) using a class vs using for loop
I have 3 drag targets and and one draggable. If I create the 3 drag target with a for loop, everything works as expcted: if I drag the red container on top of one of the yellow container, the drag_accept fires (it does create a button and changes the background).

def main(page: ft.Page):

    column = ft.Column(scroll=True)
    for i in range(0,3):
        column.controls.append(ft.DragTarget(content=ft.Container(bgcolor=ft.colors.AMBER, width=100, height=100),
                                            group='player', on_accept=target.drag_accept))
    
    text1= ft.Text(value='CODE 1', size=50, color=ft.colors.BLUE)
    page.add(ft.Row(controls=[column, draggable(), text1]) 
            )

Now, if I use the class to create the drag targets (orange boxes), when I do drag and drop, all 3 boxes are affected instead of 1.

class target(ft.Container):
    def drag_accept(e):
    src = e.page.get_control(e.src_id)
    print(e.src_id)
    # print(e.control.content)
    e.control.content.bgcolor = ft.colors.PURPLE_100
    e.control.content.content = delete_button(e.src_id)
    e.control.content.data = e.src_id
    e.control.update()

    drag_target = ft.DragTarget(group = 'player', content=ft.Container(), on_accept=drag_accept)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.width = 100
        self.height = 100
        self.bgcolor = ft.colors.AMBER
        self.content = target.drag_target

    def cretate_target(n:int):
        a = []
        for i in range(0,n):
            a.append(target())
        return a

    def main(page: ft.Page):

        text2 =ft.Text(value='CODE 2', size=50,         color=ft.colors.BLUE)
        for i in target.cretate_target(3):
        page.add(i)

        page.add(draggable(), text2)

How do I make the second method works as the first one?

Please fix the indentation in the second code block. The class code needs to be indented inside the class block.

Aside: n=int should be n: int. int is a type annotation, not a default value.

You're missing the self argument in your methods in the target class.

@Barmar, should be class target(self, ft.Container) ?

Instead of editing your question, please post your solution (perhaps as a community wiki) in a self-answer. It’s much clearer to future users coming here from Google.

No, self goes in method definitions: def drag_accept(self, e):

I reverted your last edit. Solutions should be posted in the Answer section below, not in the question.

I manage to solve it.
As per mentioned in the comments, the issue was inside the class target code.
First, drag_accept was missing self.
Second, the content of the Container was a variable outside the init code, hence was shared across all the elements.
Here the functioning code:
class target(ft.Container):
    def drag_accept(self,e):
        src = e.page.get_control(e.src_id)
        src.group = 'da'
        src.update()
        e.control.content.bgcolor = ft.colors.PURPLE_100
        e.control.content.content = delete_button(e.src_id)
        e.control.content.data = e.src_id
        e.control.update()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bgcolor = ft.colors.AMBER_100
        self.content = ft.DragTarget(group = 'player', content=ft.Container(), on_accept=self.drag_accept)
        self.width = 100
        self.height = 100
    

